# Angular JS object key value - key prefixed with "@"

Tags: c#, xml, angularjs, json.net

I've serialized an xml document to json using c#.  I've used the Newtonsoft library and when serializing an xml element it prefixes and xml element attributes with an "@".

This json is called from an $http service in Angular JS, and the json is then converted into an angular object.

It probably worth knowing that because it's a key value the json was originally an object:

```
{"story": {  "@title": "The Title",  "noOfPages": "6" } }
```

However, when I go to get the value of that property using angular, for example:

```
{{ story.@title }}
```

It doesn't like the object property being prefixed with an "@".

I have several questions:

1. Can I get angular to use object keys prefixed with an @?
2. Do you know of a regular expression that would remove the "@" from all keys (in key value object) from a json string?  For example  - { @title : "TITLE", @subtitle : "SUBTITLE" } would become { title : "TITLE", subtitle : "SUBTITLE" }?
3. Is there a setting I can pass to Newtonsoft Serializer that doesn't prefix xml attributes with an @?

Comment: use the {{title}} without the `@` sign.. also what does your code look like ... take a look at some angular tutorials and specifically the part about `ng-binding` http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp

Comment: I have built a directive that takes in the key / value as attributes.  I've worked out what I needed to do and I will post the answer at some point today.  Plus, just using {{title}} won't work as the key is @title...

Comment: Down votes, erm, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put the property key of the object in square brackets, like so:

```
{{ story["@title"] }}
```